# Android ScrollView не прокручивает до конца

Tags: android, xml, прокрутка, android-scrollview, scrollview

Пытался сделать таблицу с горизонтальной и вертикальной прокруткой и фиксированным заголовком. Разметка такая:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/data"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Горизонтальная прокрутка работает хорошо, но вертикальная - нет, прокручивает не до самого низа. Что тут не так? Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите скриншот, докуда она прокручивает

Comment: вообще, вкладывать один скролл в другой - изначально плохая идея. Вы не пробовали сделать `GridView`, или `ListView`?

Comment: @metalurgus http://s011.radikal.ru/i318/1509/f8/3c1017d892d0.jpg Я привел не весь xml, там еще TextInputLayout и кнопка. Должны быть видны все буквы. Но всегда не видно 6 последних. Будто ScrollView продолжается вниз экрана.

Comment: @metalargus Не пробовал.

Comment: Случайно не используете SlidingMenu?

Comment: @katso Нет, не использую

Comment: На реальном устройстве прокрутка работает, если в экран не влезает несколько строк. Если не влезает 1-4 примерно, то прокрутка не работает, а как добавлю еще пару-тройку символов, начинает работать.